# Magento - modify search for multiple stores

Tags: magento, search

We've got 2 magento stores configured, A and B:

Store B only shows categories and products below the catgory CAT2.

Now, when searching on store B's front-end, products from categories of store A come up. How can I avoid that? I'd like to cleanly separate products assigned to store A from those assigned to store B as store B is a specialized product segment presented with another company.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we finally set up the second store as a different website, this way we can assign products to either one or the other in the website section of the product, and search results adapt accordingly.